# How can you tell if you are running 64bit or 32bit if you don't have access to Windows or CMD?

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to repair a computer that won't start Windows or has no CMD utility on MoBo. How do I tell which version is running, 64 or 32?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are not encrypted or corrupted, access the hard drive from another operating system capable of reading NTFS (say, a Live CD of some Linux distribution) and check for the `/Program Files (x86)` folder or something of the sort, that would indicate a 64 bits operating system. You could also use the `file` command to determine which platform the system's executables have been compiled for.